# Compared values have no visual difference when testing a prop of component

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I have this code:

```
import Icon from "./icon.svg";

it("should have a prop space", () => {
    const tree = shallow(
      <Button name="button test" space={Icon} />
    );
    expect(tree.props().space).toEqual(<span>{Icon} </span>);
  });
```

When I run it, I take this as an answer:

Expected value to equal:

```
   <span>test-file-stub </span>
```

Received:

```
 <span>test-file-stub </span>
```

Difference:
     Compared values have no visual difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote JSON.stringify for both expected and received props and received this:

> Expected value to equal:
>         "{\"type\":\"span\",\"key\":null,\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"children\":[\"test-file-stub\",\"
>   \"]},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}}"
>
> Received:
>         "{\"type\":\"span\",\"key\":null,\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"children\":[\"test-file-stub\",\"
>   \",null]},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}}"